# Unix command to grep above and below until a certain text appears

Tags: xml

Consider the below example where '12345' is a unique id for the entire xml.

```
<Tag 1>
a
b
c
d
12345
x
y
z
</Tag 1>
```

I need a command where I can grep '12345' in my file and go above and below upto `<Tag 1>` and `</Tag 1>` respectively so I get the XML file for the provided id.

Comment: If you want to ask about parsing XML, please ensure that your example correctly represents your actual data. Currently, the posted example is not valid XML, and there is furthermore no indication of how to tell the line with the "id" apart from any other line in the text, or where the "Tag" node is located in the document, or whether there are other nodes like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XML-aware parser to pick the value straight out of the XML. First, let's fix up your XML snippet so that it's valid, and put it into `file.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tag_1>
a
b
c
d
12345
x
y
z
</Tag_1>
```

(1) Knowing the element name you can then use this command to pick out the value:

```
xmlstarlet select -t -v '//Tag_1' file.xml
```

Output (including a leading blank line, per the XML):

```
a
b
c
d
12345
x
y
z
```

If you really want the element tag name you can add it back in again:

```
xmlstarlet select -t -e Tag_1 -v '//Tag_1' file.xml; echo
```

In both cases the selector `//Tag_1` will match all occurrences of the element `Tag_1`. You can and should be more precise with an XPath selector. For example, with this snippet you can pick out the `stuff` using `/root/item/Tag_1`:

```
<root>
    <item><Tag_1>stuff</Tag_1></item>
    <unwanted><Tag_1>nonsense</Tag_1></unwanted>
</root>
```

---

(2) It's struck me that I've misread the question and you actually want the element name that matches the desired content. In this case it's a [more complicated expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060492/2344631) but this give you the immediate element name(s) that contain the desired text `12345`:

```
xmlstarlet select -t -m '//*[contains(text(), "12345")]' -m 'ancestor::*' -b -v 'name()' -n file.xml
```

Output

```
Tag_1
```

If required, you can either use this solution to identify the element and then use my earlier solution to extract the corresponding data, or you can extend the expression for this solution to include the content too:

```
xmlstarlet select -T -t -m '//*[contains(text(), "12345")]' -m 'ancestor::*' -b -v 'concat("<", name(), ">", ., "</", name(), ">")' -n file.xml
```

---

If you don't have `xmlstarlet` you should find that it's a standard package and really easy to install. Or for your systems administrators to install for you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the file name `text.xml`, and we want to get the data from the above of the  search string that is `12345`.

### Grep the Above content

```bash
string=`grep -n 12345 text.xml | awk -F: '{print $1}'` && head -n -$(( string - 1 )) text.xml
```

The output will look like -

```
<Tag 1>
a
b
c
d
```

### Grep the Below content

```bash
string=`grep -n 12345 text.xml | awk -F: '{print $1}'` && tail -n +$(( string + 1 )) text.xml
```

The output will look like this -

```
12345
x
y
z
</Tag 1>
```

Comment: Note that this would also match lines where `12345` occurs as a substring anywhere in the document. Additionally, you would not be able to tell the unique identifier `12345` apart from any other occurrence of the string `12345` since `grep` does not know what an identifier is in XML.

Comment: Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser

Comment: (1) Even assuming there's only one match in the file, putting these two suggestions together will give `12345` from both results, effectively doubling it up. How do you propose to handle that?

Comment: (2) If there are a different number of lines before and after the `12345` token your code will mismatch because it's built on a fixed number of lines before/after. Do you have a suggestion to deal with this?

Comment: (3) If there is any other (XML) data before (or after) the required (but invalid) `<Tag 1/>` element header/trailer your code will include it

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my @xml = open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str).getElementsByTagName("tag");  \
                  .put for @xml.grep(/12345/);'  file
```

Use Raku's `XML` module to parse XML:

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML

Sample Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <tag id="1">
  a
  b
  c
  d
  12345
  x
  y
  z
  </tag>
</catalog>
```

Sample Output:

```
<tag id="1">
  a
  b
  c
  d
  12345
  x
  y
  z
  </tag>
```

If you want to drop the tags (return the `contents`), and just return `char`-acter containing `lines` that have been `trim`med of leading whitespace, then just ask Raku to give that to you:

```perl
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my @xml = open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str).getElementsByTagName("tag").map(*.contents);  \
                  .trim-leading.put if .chars for @xml.grep(/12345/).lines;' file 
a
b
c
d
12345
x
y
z
```

https://raku.org